# Maven release plugin - how to bump version of release project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I am using maven release plugin with Jenkins for CICD. For various reasons, we don't do SNAPSHOTs as we are supposed. We set up Jenkins to run build against master branch with version like 0.1, 1.0. And we would like to up the version number of release every time we run Jenkins. These are the commands I had in Jenkinsfile:

```
sh "mvn -B release:clean"
sh "mvn -B release:prepare"
sh "mvn -B release:perform"
```

Ended up getting error `You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list`. No surprise there since `release:prepare` always looks for a SNAPSHOT branch. Is there a way to get around it? I found this option `-DignoreSnapshots` for `prepare` but it did not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The release plugin is intended to have a `1.0-SNAPSHOT` before running release plugin `mvn -B release:prepare` where it will change the version to a release version `1.0` and afterwards it will change them to `1.1-SNAPSHOT`(so called next dev version). During `release:perform` the tagged state of your build `1.0` will be checked out from version control and will be executing `mvn clean deploy`.

Furthermore using the release plugin can be done via:

```
mvn -B release:prepare release:perform
```

And in cases where something is going wrong you can do `mvn release:clean` (but you need to remove tags if have been created manually).

If you will have only releases that will not work...Apart from that `SNAPSHOT` is not a branch it is a version thing...

You can accomplish what you like via [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) and [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/):

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
 -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\
   ${parsedVersion.minorVersion}. \
   ${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} \
  versions:commit
```

After that you should commit this changes into version control (best be done via Pipelines in Jenkins). Furthermore via [scm-maven-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html):

```
mvn scm-maven-plugin:commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible with maven release plugin. You should have SNAPSHOTs for that.

But if you need just update project version you can use  maven version plugin

see http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html